# Can you identify the "Tank Limo"?

Tags: military, identification, tanks

[Dame Vivienne Westwood uses a "tank" to protest fracking](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2015/09/11/-dame-vivienne-westwood-drives-tank-to-david-camerons-house-in-fracking-protest_n_8122594.html?1441980888&ncid=tweetlnkushpmg00000067). It's not a tank, but a strange Armored Personnel Carrier that I cannot identify.  The markings indicate it is the ["Tank Limo" hired from Tanks-A-Lot](http://tanklimo.com/tank_limo_hire.htm).  It has seven road wheels, three return rollers, a front sprocket drive, a squat turret with what is likely a low velocity cannon, and a large crew door in the rear.

[image: "Tank Limo" side view]
[image: "Tank Limo" rear view]

The web site indicates it is a Cold War relic and may be a prototype.

> A bit of a special not only fitted with a turret for when it was on the Berlin wall, and one of only 13 ever made but she also had some strange mine laying or clearing gismo on its rear which we binned.

It looks like a stretched [FV432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FV432), but who stretched it and why?

I found [another reference to a turreted FV432 used to patrol the Berlin Wall](https://www.flickr.com/photos/clurr/3582421774/in/photostream/).  It does not appear to be stretched.

Comment: Its not a tank, its an APC. There are a lot of customized APCs out there.

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes, I said that in the second sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the page you linked to, it was made by the company that hire it out.

> we pulled out the best armored personnel carrier from 30 we had laying around. A bit of a special not only fitted with a turret for when it was on the Berlin wall, and one of only 13 ever made...Chopped a few windows in the side fitted smoked glass Fridge; twin DVD's reversing cameras completely re trimmed the interior. We found the army had left the massive diesel powered crew heater in one of the 432,s so we threw that in as well.

So it's a modified FV432 as you guessed. Apparently, some of them had a [scorpion tank turret](http://arcaneafvs.com/fv432turr.html) fitted (with dummy gun) as part of OPFOR exercises, presumably to look a bit like a Russian BMP. Others, as the quote suggests, used a [turret](http://www.khakicorpsimports.com/vehicles/in-fox-2.jpg) taken from the Fox armoured cars (which had a 30mm Rarden cannon) and were deployed in Berlin in the 1960s. The PRP256D registration on the vehicle was issued in 1966, so could be original.

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=St5AWK0xxhk) from The Fifth Gear TV programme, this vehicle is actually two FV432s welded together (Listen at the two minute mark). The 30mm cannon has been removed leaving just the shortened barrel housing.

Comment: Further down it says *"The vehicle is 2 former British Army FV432 APC (still in service) welded together with an original 2 man turret of the FV432 used in the Berlin Brigade. in addition too the 2 man turret, over 10 people can be comfortably seated in the plush rear section of the hull. Windows are mounted in the hulls sides and a TV screen is also installed."*